# Retrieving float from generic dictionary

Tags: generics, dictionary, unity-game-engine, floating-point

I am using a generic dictionary in Unity (uJS) to store a string [key] and a float [value]. However I can’t seem to access it the float value by passing the string key.

I am sure the float values are present in the dictionary as they return properly when iterated over using the the key value pairs, so I must be trying to access the value wrong; can anyone enlighten me as to where this issue may be occurring?
Have tried a whole number of approaches available in reference documentation to no avail.

Many thanks in advance,

Ryan

**Function:**

```js
function findXOrigin(numberOfGroupings : int, groupings : List.<String>)
{
 var floorPlaneCol = floorPlane.GetComponent(BoxCollider); 
 var floorSizeX = floorPlaneCol.size.x;
 Debug.Log("floorSizeX: " + floorSizeX);
 
 var floorSubdivisionSize = floorSizeX / numberOfGroupings;
 Debug.Log("floorSubdivisionSize: " + floorSubdivisionSize);
 
 groupingsOrigin = new Dictionary.<String, float>();
 
 for (var group : String in groupings)
 { 
  var subDivLength = floorSizeX - floorSubdivisionSize;
  floorSizeX -= floorSubdivisionSize; //removes accounted for section from the overall size
  var subDivXOrigin = subDivLength + (floorSubdivisionSize/2);
  groupingsOrigin.Add(group, subDivXOrigin);
 }
```

**Debugs Correctly:**

```
for (var group : KeyValuePair.<String, float> in groupingsOrigin)
{
    var groupOrigin = groupingsOrigin.Values;
    Debug.Log("Dictionary entry= " + " Group Name: " +group.Key + " " + " Group X Origin: " + group.Value);

}
```

**Debugs Incorrectly:** (also trialled w/ TryGetValue etc)

```
    for (var group : String in groupingsOrigin.Keys)
{
    var groupOriginX = groupingsOrigin[group];
    //var groupOriginX : float;
    //groupingsOrigin.TryGetValue(group, groupOriginX);
    Debug.Log("Dictionary entry= " + " Group Name: " + group + " " + " Group X Origin: " + groupOriginX.ToString);
}
```

**Error Return:**

Instead of returning `Dictionary entry=  Group Name: Home Scan  Group X Origin: 8.333334` like in the first method, the second method returns `Dictionary entry=  Group Name: Home Scan  Group X Origin: CompilerGenerated.__BrowseImpSortPositionObj_findXOrigin$callable1$120_117__
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `groupOriginX.ToString()` instead of `groupOriginX.ToString`. Or just `groupOriginX`.

When you use `ToString` without parenthesis, you refer to the function `ToString`, not calling it. So this is what you get - `ToString` is an object of type `CompilerGenerated.__BrowseImpSortPositionObj_findXOrigin$callable1$12...`